# Get all posts WHERE custom_field is LIKE value

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, query-posts

I'm trying to do a MySQL-style search with Wordpress' built-in functions for fetching posts. There's likely a simple way to do this and I'm probably just a little bit off from the solution.

We have posts with custom fields in them. This is legacy data imported as a custom post type with custom_fields being the extra data from our older database. The custom fields are setup like this for each post in Wordpress right now:

```
key = subject
val = Subject One, Subject Two, Subject Three
```

I'm trying to fetch all posts where custom_field value is LIKE "Subject Two", as an example. There's probably an easy way to do this that just hasn't hit me yet. Thanks for your help!

I already have a properly working MySQL query. Just wanted to use Wordpress' functions to handle the query instead of me having to do it manually for this theme view. Here's the working example:

```
// Get posts that match LIKE this subject
$cft_by_subject = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT
        wp_posts.ID,
        wp_posts.post_title,
        wp_posts.post_date,
        wp_posts.post_name,
        wp_postmeta.meta_value
     FROM
        wp_posts,
        wp_postmeta
     WHERE
        (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) AND
        (wp_posts.post_type = 'our-custom-post-type') AND
        (wp_posts.post_status = 'Publish') AND
        (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'subject') AND
        (wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%".$this-is-our-subject."%')
     ORDER BY
        wp_posts.ID ASC
    ",
    ARRAY_A
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use meta_query in [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'subject',
            'value' => 'Subject Two',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Wow. That was incredibly simple. Thanks. This worked perfectly!